# Does Transform.childCount not work correctly?

Tags: unity, transformation

This is my code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collide) {
  if (collide.gameObject.transform.tag == "Laser") {
    Debug.Log ("Inside If");
    Transform resourceTransform = collide.transform;
    Transform[] tf = new Transform[resourceTransform.childCount];
    for(int i = 0; i<= resourceTransform.childCount-1; i++){
      tf[i] = resourceTransform.GetChild(i);
    }

    Debug.Log ("Child Count Before: " + resourceTransform.childCount);
    resourceTransform.transform.DetachChildren();

    Debug.Log ("Child Count After: " + resourceTransform.childCount);
    Vector3 centerOfMass = resourceRb.centerOfMass;
    Explode (tf, centerOfMass);
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine, except the childCount property is always zero and that screws everything else up. Here's an image of the hierarchy:

[image: screenshot]

The script is on cube1 and the object has 12 or so children. So why is childCount equal to zero? Is it a problem with Unity itself?

Comment: You seem to be getting the child count of the laser.

Answer (score 2):

collide.Transform refers to the object you are colliding with. Change this line

```
Transform resourceTransform = collide.transform
```

to

```
Transform resourceTransform = transform
```

and try again